# Delete Cookies on Mobile Safari using Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, mobile-safari, appium-ios

I'm writing UI automation for a web application which runs on iOS and Android. These tests run on remote Phone devices. So far, the tests with the same URLs run successfully for Android but they fail on iOS devices.

**Root Cause:** 
I have a test suite where each test in the suite has to pass the authentication workflow and navigate to the Page Under Test. When I run the test on iPhone Safari, the first test executes fine. When the second test is started, the initial test URL directly lands on the home page (skipping the authentication part and driver still searches for Username, password fields) because the cookies are already stored on the browser.

Using `driver.manage.deleteAllCookies()` doesn't help.

Is there any way I can delete the cookies stored in Safari browser with automation?

P.S: The test suite works absolutely fine for Android platform.

**Technical Details:**

1. Test Framework - Selenium
2. Mobile Automation Framework - Appium
3. Device: iPhone - version 11 (internal tools setup on the cloud for test suite execution)
4. Browser: Safari

Comment: Why `Using driver.manage.deleteAllCookies() doesn't help`? Any error? Error stack trace please

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have stumbled into a [bug in appium for iOS](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6797).  I believe that the iOS Driver gets cookies using javascript, which means it cannot see cookies with the **httponly** or **secure** flag.  To confirm this, log into you app, then run the following code on iOS and Android:

```
int clear = 0;
int secure = 0;
Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    if(cookie.isSecure()) {
        secure++;
    } else {
        clear++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Found " + secure + " secure cookies");
System.out.println("Found " + clear + " clear cookies");
```

It may be possible to fix the behaviour in Appium using the remote debug protocol instead of javascript to work with cookies.

Workarounds could entail using a clean simulator for each run (slow) or ensuring you are fully logged out before starting your test.

Comment: I tried this but it isn't that effective as selenium doesn't have access to the cookie jar of Safari browser. Thanks for the trying to help me though

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this type of [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521482/appium-for-iphone-safari-is-not-creating-the-new-session.) 
`driver.manage.deleteAllCookies()`this method is not work on Real device(iPhone) Safari. [for Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521482/appium-for-iphone-safari-is-not-creating-the-new-session.): https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10568.

I have fixed this issue:

- After navigates to URL and check if it is already Login.
- If user is already login then logout and It will redirects to Home page then
  log in with new user.
- If user is not logged in then continue with the normal flow.

Using this flow you I have resolve issue.

Hope this will help you.

Best Luck!!!!

Comment: yes I followed this method as a temporary solution. But logging out is not a permanent solution in my case. Thanks for solution though, this worked!!

As a permanent long term solution what I am looking at is, I need to ensure the cookies and cache and cleaned out without adding additional logout step at each new browser/test session